# Changes are not applied on MVC controllers after upload web site

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I design a website with ASP.NET MVC. After I upload the website,when I change controllers, the changes are not applied on controller, even we delete a controller it still run, and I don't received any error.
It caused I can't change my controller on uploaded website.

Comment: Are you completely recompiling and publishing the changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controllers are a part of whats compiled into the dll files, changing the CS-files after your upload will not change anything, since the dll's compiled wont change until you build/rebuild them.

By the way, youre not suppose to upload your cs-files.